# Searching purchase records, with or without a vendor criterion

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

I'm trying to figure out a better way to have one query here. I want to be able to send something to last where statement a wildcard so I can select all vendors. Right now if I don't include that line it doesn't filter by vendor so I essentially get all the purchase requests.

Any thoughts of a cleaner way to do these queries?

```
 if @vendor == "0" #checks for vendor
    @purchase_requests = PurchaseRequest.includes(:purchase_order)
                          .where(:created_at => @date_start..@date_end)
                          .where(:total_cost => @cost_beginning..@cost_end)
  else
    @purchase_requests = PurchaseRequest.includes(:purchase_order)
                          .where(:created_at => @date_start..@date_end)
                          .where(:total_cost => @cost_beginning..@cost_end)
                          .where("purchaseorder.VendorRef_ListID = ?", @vendor)
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest refactor would be:

```
# this is the base query
requests = PurchaseRequest.includes(:purchase_order)
             .where(:created_at => @date_start..@date_end)
             .where(:total_cost => @cost_beginning..@cost_end)

# then we add additional conditions if required 
requests =
  unless @vendor == "0" # if vendor, get specific purchase request
    request.where("purchaseorder.VendorRef_ListID = ?", @vendor)
  end
```

If you find that you do certain queries often, the it's probably a chance to use scopes.  You may already know about scopes, but if not, check out [Mastering ActiveRecord and Arel](http://danshultz.github.io/talks/mastering_activerecord_arel/#/).

```
class PurchaseRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :purchase_order

  # requests within a certain data
  scope :date_between, ->(date_range) {
    where(:created_at => date_range)
  }

  # requests with a certain cost range
  scope :cost_between, ->(date_range) {
    where(:total_cost => date_range)
  }

  # find request for a specific vendor
  scope :for_vendor, ->(vendor) {
    # this scope does an inner join to purchase_order and adds
    # a condition that the PurchaseOrder must belong to a specific
    # vendor.  That is, only requests matching the vendor are returned
    joins(:purchase_order).merge( PurchaseOrder.for_vendor(vendor) )
  }
end

class PurchaseOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  # purchase orders belonging to a specific vendor
  scope :for_vendor, ->(vendor) {
    where(:VendorRef_ListID => vendor)
  }
end
```

So with scopes added, you can now refactor your code like so:

```
# this is the base query
requests = PurchaseRequest.includes(:purchase_order)
             .date_between(@date_start..@date_end)
             .cost_between(@cost_beginning..@cost_end)

# if vendor, get specific request
requests = request.for_vendor(@vendor) unless @vendor == "0"
```

Comment: A very well thought out and written answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also implement your code using single where with a hash.  @vendor will be an optional hash param:

```
options = {
  created_at: @date_start..@date_end,
  total_cost: @cost_beginning..@cost_end
}
options['purchaseorder.VendorRef_ListID'] = @vendor unless @vendor == "0"

@purchase_requests = PurchaseRequest.includes(:purchase_order).where(options)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

- Conditionals are expressions in Ruby, so you can write: `@purchase_requests = if ...`
- Multiple conditions can be used in the hash argument of `where`.
- Ruby is a good language to DRY code, don't repeat yourself.

To add something new to the other answers, a "declarative-abstraction-for-everything" approach might look like this (implementation of `apply_if` left to the reader):

```
@purchase_requests = PurchaseRequest.includes(:purchase_order)
  .where(created_at: @date_start..@date_end, total_cost: @cost_start..@cost_end)
  .apply_if(@vendor != "0") { where("purcharseorder.VendorRef_ListID" => @vendor) }
```